# Float is inf but integer is not inf in C++ - xCode. Why?

Tags: c++, xcode, int

Probably it's some basic question. But I can't figure it out, and find the answer.

As I know that highest number for `int` is: `-2147483648`

And when I pass that limit, compiler shows me always that highest value.

And for `float` it's: `3.4e+38` (or minus, but it's not the point)

And when I pass that limit for float, compiler shows me always `inf`. Why not `3.4e+38` or `-3.4e-38`???

My code is like that:

```
int bytesT=8*5;
int a=0;

for (int i=0; i<bytesT; i++)
{
    a += pow(2, i);
}
std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;


float b= 3.4 * pow(10, 39);
std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
```

And it gives me that result:

```
a = -2147483648
b = inf
```

Could anyone explain that behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-2147483648` is not the highest value an `int` can take. It's the smallest value it can take, and that's provided your `int` is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I'm gonna try to make this as simple as possible:  

int = 32 bits:
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
left-most bit represents sign, so largest int32 number that you can have is:  
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 (which is 2147483647)

for negative numbers if left-most bit is set to 1 then to get "human readable"  
number you will have to do complement 2 of that number which is invert every bit  
and add 1.

ex.
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111  <- my number (i know it is negative, -?)  
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  <- all bits converted  
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001  <- added 1    
=> so that begging number was -1  

Now that you know this, question is what happens if you add 1 to the   
largest positive int32 number (0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111) ?  

Well you will get 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
which is (-2147483648). What happened here was overflow caused by addition.  
This was the case in your program for your 'a' variable.

- As for your confusion with 'inf': 

Floating point numbers work differently then integers.  
I'm not gonna go into too much detail on how bits and bytes are arranged.
Just know that there is :  
 - 1 bit reserved for sign (top-left)   
 - next 8 (for float32) bits for exponent   
 - and the rest for fraction  
Now what is interesting is that there are certain 'special' values defined in
IEEE 754 which are the following:

 - +0 = 0 00000000 00000000000000000000000  
 - -0 = 1 00000000 00000000000000000000000  
 - +inf = 0 11111111 00000000000000000000000
 - -inf = 1 11111111 00000000000000000000000
 - NaN = 0 11111111 00000000000000000000001

As you see these special values are not defined in int type which is the reason  
why you get 'inf' in float and something weird/unexpected in int.

I hope i answered your question.
```

Comment: "what happens if you add 1 to the largest positive int32 number ?"; probably you should mention that C++ standard treats this as integer overflow, which leads to undefined behaviour; even if compilers may ignore the overflow and behave as you described, there is no guarantee

Answer (score 1):

`inf` stands for a value that is larger than the respective floating point type may hold. So if the highest value for `float` is `3.4e+38`, then `3.4 * pow(10, 39)` is larger (note the `39`), such that `float` will represent this value as special  value `inf`. If you write, however, `3.4 * pow(10, 38)`, you will get (almost) the highest value.

The actual highest (and lowest) numbers are provided in `<limits>`:

```
#include <limits>

int main() {

    float b= 3.4 * pow(10, 38);
    float c= std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    cout << b << " " << c << endl;

    int imax = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int imin = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    cout << imin << " " << imax << endl;
}
```

This avoids integer overflows, which you will get in your code at some point with `a += pow(2, i)`. Note that integer overflow is undefined behaviour and  - even if it often works "as intended" - is not guaranteed to work at all.  Per Paragraph 5/4 of the C++11 Standard (regarding any expression in general):

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is undefined. [...]

Comment: This is a great explanation of `inf`. But I feel the answer should also discuss `int` overflow and why `a += pow(2, 39)` is a bad idea where `a` is a 32 bit signed `int`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with François Andrieux. Great thanks for answer and explanation what `inf` is. But exact point of my question was "Why for integers I don't get inf, but instead I get highest possible number?" Is it standard behaviour or just for xCode, or maybe just for OS X system? I don't have Windows now for test it, but as I remember in Windows, compilers show some random number for integers over limits. But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Integers don’t usually have an “infinite” for or any other flagged state. They just have values. What you are doing here by using powers of 2 is setting bits to 1 one by one, having int be 32bit. This means you’ll end up with value which as two’s complement is the smallest value a signed int can have. If the value were unsigned it would be the largest. If you add to a 32bit value a value with all zeroes in the lowest 32 bits nothing changes. So you’ll end up with this value.

(IEEE) floating point values work differently. They have flags indicating infinities, not-a-number etc. Therefore it makes sense to use these when the value goes out of bounds. That’s why you end up with inf when you add too many numbers and the value goes out of bounds.

If you keep adding 1 to an int variable you’ll see it doesn’t stay in any single value. It will overflow and keep on going. I’m not sure how much C++ specification defined how these should be handled, so it may even be implementation specific, but usually values overflow and keep on going forever around and around.

Comment: I experienced all things you told here. So it's normal behaviour? Not only unix system, or xCode compiler?